# How to use password retrieved from `pass` in a shell script

Tags: bash, terminal

I stored a password in using the [`pass`](http://tuxlabs.com/?p=450) and based I am trying to automate a VPN Connection process using Cisco Anyconnect. The VPN works, I confirmed that. The [script](https://superuser.com/a/726542/757155) I am trying to use is:

```
pass=$(pass branch/key)
vpn -s connect vpn.server.host << "EOF"
0
username
"$pass"
y
exit
EOF
```

Suppose I save that as `.connectvpn` and say `source .connectvpn` then it should start a VPN tunnel and get a connection going.

If in the file I get rid of the variable I am trying to use (`pass`), and put the actual password on the fifth line I know it works. The trouble I am having is with the bash variable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have quoted the delimiter, `"EOF"`. When the delimiter of a here-document is quoted, no parameter expansion is performed on the body, so your password gets its literal value, `"$pass"`. Try using `EOF` without quotes as a delimiter.